# How to use VS Code debugger for C?

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code

I know there is a similar question on this topic but I've already tried the solution there and it didn't work. I'm trying to debug a simple C program using VS Code but nothing is happening, the blue bar keeps loading forever but the debugger doesn't start. These are the contents of `launch.json`:

```
 "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "D:\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```